# Can Cucumber '--require' more than 1 folder?

Tags: cucumber

Can I `--require` more than 1 different folder? Can a 2nd or 3rd parameter appear after `--require`?

Is this correct syntax?

```
cucumber --require ./folder1/ ./folder2/ --tags ${groups} --format json -o cucumber.json
```

Comment: Ruby Cucumber or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Ruby Cucumber can `--require` (or `-r`) more than one folder. `cucumber --help` doesn't clearly say whether it's supported, but it's an easy experiment, and it works for me. You need to say `---require` before each directory you're requiring, however. For example, if you want to `--require` `folder1` and `folder2`, do

```
cucumber --require folder1 --require folder2
```

If you `--require` any folder, Cucumber no longer implicitly requires `features`, so if e.g. you have step definitions in `features` and some support code in `folder1` you need to explicitly `--require` them both:

```
cucumber --require features --require folder1
```

Note that `--require` only controls requiring of Ruby code; even with `--require`, Cucumber still looks for features in `features` by default. But you can ask it to run multiple features or directories of features:

```
cucumber features1 features2
```

Again, if you specify some features to run and still want to run features in the `features` directory you have to explicitly say so:

```
cucumber features features1
```

Do consider carefully whether you want to require everyone who runs your Cucumber suite to have to know about its non-standard structure. It might be easier for everyone to require the code you need in a support file. For example, if `folder1` has a single file `folder1.rb`, instead of running Cucumber with `--require folder1` every time you could put the following in `support/folder1.rb` and run Cucumber normally:

```
require_relative '../../folder1/folder1.rb'
```